# SQL how to select a column from a foreign key without join

Tags: sql

I hope you guys can help me. I have 2 tables 1 called `Stuk` and one is called `Niveau`.

In the table `Stuk` I have a FK from the table `Niveau`. This is the column `niveaucode` the skill codes I have are:

```
A EXAMPLE 1
B EXAMPLE 2
C EXAMPLE 3
```

If I select a musicpiece I don't want to see A, B or C I want to see EXAMPLE 1, EXAMPLE 2 or EXAMPLE 3. I have to do this without a JOIN

[image: enter code here]

Comment: then you can use CASE, e.g. CASE WHEN STUK.niveaucode='A' THEN 'EXAMPLE 1' END

Comment: @Sergey where do I add this in this statement: `SELECT [stuknr], [genrenaam] FROM dbo.Stuk
WHERE [jaartal] > 1995`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT S.[stuknr], S.[genrenaam],
CASE
  WHEN S.niveaucode='A' THEN 'EXAMPLE 1' 
  WHEN S.niveaucode='B' THEN 'EXAMPLE 2'
  WHEN S.niveaucode='C' THEN 'EXAMPLE 3'
  ELSE 'HMM'
END AS FLAG
FROM dbo.Stuk S 
WHERE  S.[jaartal] > 1995
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will answer your question:

```
select stuknr, componistid, titel, stuknrorigineel, genrenaam, omskrijving, speeldur, jaartal 
from stuk a, niveau b where a.niveaukode = b.niveaukode
```

Sorry if I misspelled any of your attributes (I didn't double check, and I don't know dutch)

Comment: Please use modern  `JOIN` operator for tables

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev The question specifically said to do it without join